# Change html elements value from servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, label

I have a `label` in jsp file with value "welcome".

and a `button` which will redirect to `servlet`.

Now from `servlet` i want to change the value of `label` on the basis of of some logic.

Thanks

Comment: You should use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you cannot directly set JSP/HTML elements value from servlet. But you can store a session variable form servlet and then check this session variable is available in JSP on onload event. If yes get value from session variable and set that value in HTML element. Also dont forget to reset the session variable if it is no longer used.

serevlet:

```
<%request.getSession.SetAttribute("attr","value");%>
```

JSP

```
<%
if(request.getSession.getAttribute("attr")){
%>
<label><%=request.getSession.getAttribute("attr")%></label>

<%
request.getSession.removetAttribute("attr");
}
%>
```